# docker-compose up recreates container when config is unchanged

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am not clearly understand how docker-compose realizes when to recreate container or where not.
My case is:

```
docker-compose -f conf.yml up // Ok
docker-compose -f conf.yml up // xxx is up-to-date
```

Then I do:

```
docker-compose -f /copy/conf.yml up // Recreating container
```

But copy/conf.yml is same as conf.yml
Why docker-compose recreates container, while it's config is unchanged? Its only loaded from other path. How docker-compose handles this stuff? 
It must says "up-to-date", if config is same, despite of config's path (I know about --no-recreate flag, but I want to know how things works)

Comment: Is the directory name the same? In other words is the project name that appears at the front of each container name the same?

Comment: Yep.
     `docker_db_1 is up-to-date`
then
    `Recreating docker_db_1`
Sometimes no, it says:
 `Recreating 8616c4b6e5b2_docker_db_1`

Comment: I don't trust the output of those lines since I've seen things get misreported before. Can you double check the output of `docker ps`? And also verify that `diff conf.yml /copy/conf.yml` outputs no changes?

Comment: The yml files are same for sure (just copied again to be sure). And what about docker ps, how it can be helpful? It outputs container ids and so on.

Comment: Just double checking that a second instance with a different name didn't get spun up. Did your image get rebuilt?

Comment: No more second instance with hashes at front.
Only one with same name - docker_db_1.
docker ps before and after recreating are different (only by container id)

Comment: Hashes at the front? If the directory name is /copy, then you'd see copy_db_1. And just to double check, I edited my last comment after you probably saw it, did your image get rebuilt?

Comment: No, my image never rebuild coz no reason for this

Comment: No further ideas from me, full output of your `docker-compose up` would help because I can't reproduce this here.

Comment: Well, I simplified a bit. My case is: /app and /app_copy, with exactly same files. docker-compose up in one and then docker-compose up in other

Comment: The "project name" is the path.   Different path = different project.    See if the -p option does whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well. Looks like I found. What is the reason is. 
in yml I has this mount line:
`- ./hosts:/root/hosts` It is the same in both yml. BUT, mount point is different. When I remove this, it not recreates even if config from different path

Comment: *in `volumes:` section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one folder is /app/conf.yml and the other folder is /app_copy/conf.yml, then you'll find that docker creates two different "projects", one for "app" and the other for "appcopy" (it removes non-alphanumeric characters and makes it all lower case). The project is the first part of each container name by default, it's named `$project_$service_$instance`.

If you specify the container name inside your docker-compose.yml, then docker-compose will recreate it if you have things like volume mounts to the current folder which would be different. Otherwise, if the compose files are truly identical, the source image hasn't changed, and there are no externalities that would be different, then I'm not able to reproduce this one.

Here's an example without a fixed container_name:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up -d
Creating test_testapp_1

$ docker-compose -f test/docker-compose.test.yml up -d
test_testapp_1 is up-to-date
```

Below is what happens if you try to specify a container name in the compose file:

```
$ pwd
..../test

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.name.yml up -d
Starting unique_name

$ docker-compose -f subdir/docker-compose.name.yml up -d
Creating network "subdir_default" with the default driver
Creating unique_name

ERROR: for test  Cannot create container for service test: Conflict. The container name "/unique_name" is already in use by container 80b44bc94912b755cf2430b132fa6112f960e2752f69a357c27375bbc905ff76. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

$ mv subdir test

$ docker-compose -f test/docker-compose.name.yml up -d
unique_name is up-to-date
```